# Store multiple html elements in variable with React

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

I have some repetitive code which renders some html in a React component. I would like to store the repetitive html elements in a variable and return them but am unable to do this.

```js
const renderAddress = event => {
  if (event.venue.address.address_2) {
    return (
      <address>
        {event.venue.address.address_2}
        <br />
        {event.venue.address.address_1}
        <br />
        {event.venue.address.city}
        <br />
        {event.venue.address.postal_code}
      </address>
    )
  } else {
    return (
      <address>
        {event.venue.address.address_1}
        <br />
        {event.venue.address.city}
        <br />
        {event.venue.address.postal_code}
      </address>
    )
  }
}
```

Ideally I would like something like this:

```js
const renderAddress = event => {
  const base = (
        {event.venue.address.address_1}
        <br />
        {event.venue.address.city}
        <br />
        {event.venue.address.postal_code}
        )
  if (event.venue.address.address_2) {
    return (
      <address>
        {event.venue.address.address_2}
        <br />
        {base}
      </address>
    )
  } else {
    return (
      <address>
        {base}
      </address>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your ideal approach seems like a great way to compose the final `<address>` element. You can achieve this using [Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) as the issue/error would be around `base`'s contents in `renderAddress(event)` would need to be wrapped with some element to avoid errors attempting to render values such as `{event.venue.address.address_1}`. A `React.Fragment` would allow you to render `base` while avoiding introducing additional rendered wrapper elements:

```
const renderAddress = event => {
  const base = (
    <React.Fragment>
      {event.venue.address.address_1}
      < br />
      {event.venue.address.city}
      < br />
      {event.venue.address.postal_code}
    </React.Fragment>
  );

  if (event.venue.address.address_2) {
    return (
      <address>
        {event.venue.address.address_2}
        <br />
        {base}
      </address>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <address>
        {base}
      </address>
    );
  }
};
```

Here is a basic [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-txdfqz) in action.

**Note:** `React.Fragment` is only available with React version 16.2+.

Answer (score 2):

I like JSX and the ways you can manipulate it, so, thought I'd post an answer, too.

Use a combination of an array, which is easy to manipulate, and native JSX-rendering, like so...

```
const renderAddress = event => {
  var address_pieces = [];

  if (event.venue.address.address_2) {
    address_pieces.push(event.venue.address.address_2);
  }

  address_pieces.push(event.venue.address.address_1);
  address_pieces.push(event.venue.address.city);
  address_pieces.push(event.venue.address.postal_code);

  return (
    <address>
      {address_pieces.map(address_piece => {
        return (
          <span>
            {address_piece}
            <br />
          </span>
        );
      })}
    </address>
  );
};
```

This removes the redundant parts of your code, and gives you some new JS tools to work with, like `map()`.

I have also coded up a full, working sample here: https://codesandbox.io/s/r1w60ozo3o